# Estimated population of Atlantis in Marvel Comics

Tags: marvel, atlantis

While acquainting myself with the war between Atlantis and Wakanda, I found myself wondering what the population of Atlantis is.
Any and every scan relevant to the discussion irrespective of the time period would be appreciated.